# How to Sync ToggleButton with Keypress

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created a Dojo Toggle button to perform an action of bolding text.

```
var button3 = new ToggleButton({
            label: label,
             showLabel: false,
             iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIcon"+label,
            onClick: function(){ 
              /* Bold operation */

            }
```

The bold operation can also happen using ctrl+b.

How can I sync both of them such that when i do ctrl+b, the toggle button also gets highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// connect dojo/on

```
on(document, 'onkeydown', function(event)){
    if(event.keyCode === 66 && event.ctrlKey){
        // bold operation
    }    
}
```

Comment: I used the above with the aspect.after function and it worked :)